# How to use Set as Wallpaper using cordova plugin in Ionic Framework?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building **Ionic based wallpaper app**.Wallpapers are displayed using **ionic cards img tags**.

I am trying to use **cordova-plugin-wallpaper** plugin to set image in app as device wallpaper.

Can anyone explain the steps on how to use this plugin?

Help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://github.com/fbsanches/cordova-plugin-wallpaper#usage).